# Falta revisar "Comments use mini-Markdown formatting…"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducida-falta-revisar

Ya está traducida la cadena siguiente, falta revisarla:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  [link](http://example.com) *italic* **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work.

Liga a transifex [Comments use mini-Markdown formatting…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/131930161?key=8b4803ddb471e438116d37e5ed945099)

Comment: La he revisado, pero me sale el siguiente mensaje: "_Falta la traducción del glosario por trimestre «user» en la traducción_"

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Entiendo que ese mensaje se puede ignorar. Se mencionó en el chat.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro : Mira este comentario de Mariano -> https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42742450#42742450

Comment: Al final acabé haciendo un cambio para usar la palabra del glosario. Pero aprobada está. Dime si se ve bien o hago un cambio rápido.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Se ve bien. Gracias.

Comment: @Alvaro el glosario lo van definiendo los propios usuarios... Esa advertencia significa que una palabra no coincidió ***exactamente*** con la que se usó en el glosario. Por ejemplo, si el glosario incluye `active=activa`, pero alguien usa `activas` (en plural), muestra la advertencia... Es decir, sirve como guía, pero es más que lógico que ignoremos las advertencias cuando no corresponden... Igual en este caso estaba perfecta la corrección :-)